# How to select an element with 3 classes?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have some buttons with the class `btn btn-info` and when I click on them their class would be `btn btn-info active`.The scenario is this that I want from buttons with `btn btn-info` class to do something that the `btn btn-info active`s wont do.It means I want that when I click on a button that its class is `btn btn-info` it show me an alert and when its class is `btn btn-info active` nothing happen by clicking on it.

Note:

I have tried:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $(".btn btn-info").click(function () {
        alert("salam");
    });
});
```

But it didnt work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether it has the active class:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $(".btn.btn-info").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active') == false) {
            alert("salam");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: He's not looking for this, he's trying to figure out how multiple selectors work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the selector :not like this :

```
$(".btn.btn-info:not(.active)").click(function () {
  alert("salam");
});
```

You can see here the doc of jQuery : http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: The result is just inverse.Means the .btn btn-info active classes do the click event but .btn btn-info classes dont.Thank you friend.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".btn.btn-info").click(function() { alert("Salam!"); });
```

Or, if you want to make sure it contains both parts:

```
$(".btn, .btn-info").click(function() { alert("Salam!"); });
```

Comment: The second one select all elements that have class `btn` and/or class `btn-info`. Neither solution is looking at the active class at all.

Comment: The click event is done in both .btn btn-info and .btn btn-info active.So it didnt work.Thank you.